# Normalização de tabelas MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou criando um sistema para cadastrado de funcionário, porem, gostaria de começar de forma normalizada; pensei algo assim

```
tb_funcionario (id_func, id_funcao, id_depto, nome_func, data_nasc, end_fun, dt_admissao, dt_demissao)

tb_funcao (id_func,id_depto,nome_funcao)

tb_depto (id_depto, nome_depto)
```

O que da para melhorar ou acrescentar de tal forma que fique dentro dos padrões., grato pela colaboração.

Comment: Poderia descrever melhor como o sistem vai funcionar isso ajuda identificar como devem ser os relacionamentos entre as tabelas. Como está parece adequado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Antes de falar a respeito de normalização, algumas coisas a serem observadas são:**

- Na normalização de nomes não tenha medo de escrever bastante, é muito melhor algo como: *id_funcionario_externo* em vez de *id_fun_ex*. Além de mais fácil de entender não vai deixar seu banco de dados mais pesado.
- Utilizar os tipos de dados mais adequados, assim sendo:

  - IDs: utilizar um tipo de dado inteiro, possivelmente que o tipo `SMALLINT` é mais do que o suficiente mas pode escolher algum outro que se enquadre também (Link: [Tipos Inteiros](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html)).
  - Datas: Utilizar tipos `Date` pois está querendo guardar apenas a data e assim vai poder utilizar funções para fazer `Selects` facilmente.
  - Campos de Texto: Em campos de texto que o tamanho pode ser variável (como em *nome_func*) opte por usar `varchar` em vez de `char` pois o `char` armazena todo o espaço definido e o `varchar` conforme necessário (Link: [Varchar e Char](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html))
- Recomendo ainda que na tabela *tb_funcionario* você insira um campo para RG e/ou CPF para que defina ele como `unique key` para garantir que exista nenhum funcionário duplicado. Apesar de ser algo raro duas pessoas podem ter exatamente o mesmo nome.

**Problemas de normalização -> Primeira Forma Normal:**

- Sua tabela *tb_funcao* e *tb_funcionario* possuem o *id_depto*, isso pode gerar duplicidade de dado desnecessário ou mesmo informações incorretas.
- `Primary Keys`: Definir os campos *id_func*, *id_func* e *id_depto* como `Primary Key`.
- `Foreigns Keys`: Nos campos *id_func*,*id_depto* da tabela *tb_funcao* definir como `Foreign Key` e fazer a relação correta.

**Para mais informações recomendo:** [Normalização em BD](http://www.blogdati.com.br/index.php/2010/03/normalizacao-em-banco-de-dados/)

Answer (score 4):

Uma sugestão usando o que postou:

```
tb_funcionario (id_func, id_funcao, id_depto, nome_func, data_nasc, end_fun, dt_admissao, dt_demissao)

tb_funcao (id_func,id_depto,nome_funcao)

tb_depto (id_depto, nome_depto)
```

Ficaria assim:

```
person(
  id unique,
  datebirth,
  person_name,
  person_surname
)

person_addresses(
  id unique,
  person_id,
  country_code,
  postal_code,
  province_code,
  city,
  address
  address_add
)

person_roles(
  id unique,
  role_id,
  person_id
  date_ini (data de início ou admissão)
  date_end (data de término ou demissão)
)

roles(
  id unique
  title
)

department(
  id unique
  title
)

department_roles(
  id unique
  role_id
)
```

Abaixo, vou explicar apenas alguns motivos da modelagem acima, sem abranger os tipos de dados (integer, var, date, etc).

O primeiro passo é padronizar a nomenclatura e, para tal, o recomendado é seguir um padrão internacionalizado usando o idioma inglês, pois é o mais difundido no mundo.

Conforme comentado pelo Giovani, evite abreviar os nomes das colunas. Descreva-os com clareza.

Removi redundâncias dos nomes das tabelas e nomes de colunas, exemplo, usar "tb_" para tabelas é desnecessário pois já são uma tabelas.
A coluna end_fun é um tanto confusa, lembrando algo como "end function", "fim de função?".. 
Mas pensando bem, parece ser "endereço do funcionário".

Se for endereço, então como fazer se o funcionário possuir mais de um endereço?
Aí nesse ponto a modelagem está engessada. Terá problemas futuros e muito trabalho para remodelar para múltiplos endereços.
Note que na tabela "person_addresses" possui uma coluna para código do país.
Então muitos pensam, "mas o sistema será só no meu país por quê preciso de código de país?".
Mais uma vez caímos na questão de globalização.
Pense num funcionário imigrante, um boliviano, argentino, colombiano, e isso é muito comum no Brasil. Então a empresa precisa registrar esse funcionário mas ele não possui endereço fixo no Brasil mas obviamente tem endereço fixo no país natal. Se o sistema não permitir endereços internacionais, terá então uma limitação no sistema.

Por quê troquei tb_funcionario por "person"?
Para que a estrutura seja útil para outras situações e não fique amarrada somente a cadastro de "funcionários".
Essa mesma tabela pode ser usada para clientes, por exemplo, e esse também o motivo de remover outras colunas como id_depto, id_funcao, etc, e organizá-los em tabelas de  relacionamentos.

Em "person_roles" é onde faz os relacionamentos entre o id da pessoa e o id da função.
Nessa tabela contém também data de início/admissão e término/demissão. As datas poderiam estar também numa outa tabela, mas acho desnecessário.
Pode ter casos onde uma mesma pessoa entra e sai de um cargo num departamento e retorna ao mesmo cargo e departamento. Por isso, deve permitir múltiplas entradas para uma mesma pessoa.

Prefira algo mais genérico pois nem sempre a data de término num cargo quer dizer demissão.
A pessoa/funcionário pode ser transferido ou promovido ou simplesmente terminou algum estágio, faleceu, adoeceu, gravidez, aposentou, enfim.
O interessante seria criar mais uma tabela para fazer o relacionamento de motivos do término, caso queira ter maior controle.

Perceba também que a tabela "person_roles" permite que uma mesma pessoa tenha vários cargos. E isso é muito comum em muitas empresas ter pessoas que trabalham em 2 ou mais departamentos exercendo funções as vezes iguais ou totalmente diferentes.

Citando um exemplo, um executivo poliglota.
É do departamento administrativo cuja função principal é de trader. 
Durante o tempo que não está viajando pelo mundo, fica no escritório exercendo função de tradutor ou qualquer outra coisa. Esse é um mero exemplo de funcionário com múltiplas funções.

Sobre a modelagem proposta, como saber qual ou quais departamentos pertence um determinado funcionário?
Através do relacionamento na tabela "department_roles" obtém-se a informação.

Perceba que as tabelas são independentes umas das outras. O importante é as tabelas de relacionamento. É isso que torna o sistema flexível e reutilizável.

*As nomenclaturas, tal como a modelagem proposta é meramente uma sugestão.
Não quer dizer que deve ser exatamente como apresentado. Apenas procure entender como organizar as tabelas e criar os relacionamentos de forma mais dinâmica.
Pense sempre na reutilização da estrutura e flexibilidade do sistema.